# Switch from vw to vh depending on orientation

Tags: mobile, sass

I have such function to calc from pixels to vw and it works perfectly for portrait orientation

```
@function get-vw($target) { 
  $vw-context: (320*.01) * 1px;
  @return ($target/$vw-context) * 1vw;
}
```

But awful for landscape orientation. It's a pity but such function doesn't work

```
@function get-vw($target) { 
  $vw-context: (320*.01) * 1px;
  @media only screen and (orientation: landscape) {
    @return ($target/$vw-context) * 1vh;
  }
  @media only screen and (orientation: portrait) {
    @return ($target/$vw-context) * 1vw;
  }
}
```

Has anyone similar problem? How did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

In css (sass, less, no matter) you can't dynamically set the values. You should generates all properties for all conditions and all orientations in advance.
So `@media` blocks should be placed in element selector scope. And inside these `@media`'s you should set sizes.

Sassmeister [demo](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/561dace7c21dd64b722d69e954b91693).

**Sass:**

```
// $target: number in pixels
// $orientation: string - portrait (default) | landscape

@function get-vw($target, $orientation: portrait) { 
  $vw-context: (320 * .01) * 1px;
  $axis-unit: 1vw;

  @if ($orientation == landscape) {
    // Not shure about 240
    $vw-context: (240 * .01) * 1px;
    $axis-unit: 1vh;
  }

  @return ($target / $vw-context) * $axis-unit;
}

a {
  @media only screen and (orientation: landscape) {
    size: get-vw(12px, landscape);
  }
  @media only screen and (orientation: portrait) {
    size: get-vw(12px);
  }
}
```

**Css:**

```
@media only screen and (orientation: landscape) {
  a {
    size: 5vh;
  }
}

@media only screen and (orientation: portrait) {
  a {
    size: 3.75vw;
  }
}
```

Comment: About dynamically setting the `vw` and `vh`, you kind-of can, using css variables, as this article explains: https://css-tricks.com/the-trick-to-viewport-units-on-mobile/